# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6' in Python using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, installation, pyside6

*** Update ***
This issue was solved by whiteroom in the comments section. The issue was that the Python Interpreter setting needed to be changed to point to the correct one. The whiteroom question answer was also very helpful.

*** Original Question ***
I installed PySide6 on my MacBook and confirmed that it is installed as shown in the attached screen shot. I'm also very new to Python and using the Mac Terminal app.

```
pip3 install PySide6
```

[image]

I tried to run this simple app from the Visual Studio Code editor.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QLabel
app   = QApplication([])
label = QLabel('hello world')
label.show()
app.exec()
```

Python responded with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emad-ud-deen/Development/Python/Practice/PySide6 Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QLabel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'
```

The only way I'm able to run the apps I write with PySide6 without that error is from the command line in Terminal.

Can you tell me how to get Visual Studio Code to recognise PySide6?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same question with you, but I've just found a solution:

You can use command like this:

```
pip uninstall pyside6-addons
pip uninstall pyside6-essentials
pip uninstall pyside6
pip install pyside6-essentials
```

Actually, if you don't want to use so difficult plugins, just install PySide6-Essentials[1] is benefit for you :)

References:

[1] https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-details-on-the-new-6.3-release

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I uninstalled and reinstalled PySide6-essentials and tried to execute the test app in Visual Studio Code and also in the Qt Creator. Both responded with the same error. How do I get both editors to recognise PySide6? I can only get the test app to run from Terminal.

Comment: First, choose correct python interpreter which installed PySide6-Essential from vscode's lower right corner;

Second, install Qt for Python vscode plugins[1].

After installed plugins, you can press **F5** to execute you qt app, **right-click** from vscode file page and find **Qt-options** to crud your ui.

If you want to modify your plugins options, press **Ctrl+,**, find **Qt for Python** to do it:) 
References:
[1] https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seanwu.vscode-qt-for-python

Comment: Thanks so much! That was it! Visual Studio Code now runs the apps that have the Import PySide6 statements. I hope it's ok to ask a related question. I also have the Qt Creator installed and set the Python Interpreter location like in Visual Studio Code but the software looks for PySide2 and I'm trying to run the same app with the Import PySide6 statement. Do you know where in the Qt Creator I can tell it not to look for PySide2 and change it to look for PySide6?

Comment: Ahh... I'm not so good at Qt Creator cuz I use **Qt Designer** more than it, but from my experiences, **uic** can translate **.ui** file into **.py** file, you can find **path/to/your/PySide6** to find **uic.exe** to do it. By the way, **Qt for Python** plugins can hot reload translation using **Qt Designer**, which is beneficial for me :)

Comment: I'm also now using the designer along with Visual Studio Code. I would like to use Qt Creator but it's just a minor inconvenience to need to flip over to Visual Studio Code instead of just trying to run the app from Qt Creator.

Comment: in my case, only need to run this 'pip install pyside6-essentials'

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed this problem on PyCharm by going into Settiings->Project->Python Interpreter->press '+' button then write what do you need to install.

When I tried to do installing by using pip install it was not working at all

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35650567)

Answer (score -1):

the problem with me was I have installed pyside6 but it show no module error because the python interpreter version was different in vs code and I cannot change due to some error
To resolve this, I navigated to the path location where Python was installed on my laptop. There, I located the python.exe file associated with the correct Python version and deleted it.
Upon returning to Visual Studio Code, I refreshed the Python interpreter list, which allowed me to select the python.exe corresponding to the desired Python version installed on my laptop. And it the Pyside started working again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As written, this sounds like you propose deleting a `python.exe` (which sounds dangerous on its own), then pointing VS Code to the deleted python. Please, edit this post and try for [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Also consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -2):

you can simply fix this problem by just changing the current version of your python to 3.8.10 from the down-right corner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).